# cant we write subquery in select statement in peoplesoft queries

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-query

Cant we write sub queries in select statement of sql/views of peoplesoft as follows

```
select t1.*,  
(select count(id) from t as t2 where t2.id<=t1.id) as row_number  
from t as t1 order by Id
```

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 2):

You can.

Save your record as SQL View. The Query View type is for using the Query tool, which is a graphical editor more suited for those not familiar with SQL. It has certain limitations regarding non-standard SQL constructs.

In a SQL View, you can write down the query SQL directly.